# Is it possible to search nested objects in ElasticSearch with the lucene query syntax?

Tags: elasticsearch, lucene

I really like the simple composability of the Lucene query language with ElasticSearch. We've just started using nested objects, and I understand that I [need to use a nested query to search them](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-nested-query.html), but I can't find any information anywhere on making a nested query using the Lucene syntax.

If it is possible, is there some documentation somewhere?

I've done fairly extensive googling for "elasticsearch lucene" and I'm hard pressed to find the occasional blog post mentioning the syntax, let alone actual documentation. Likewise, searching here on Stack Overflow has been pretty fruitless.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is currently not supported by Lucene.

There are a few related issues in the Elastic Github repo, but the main one is available at [#11322 Support for nested query syntax within query string query DSL](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/11322)

And the related pull request: [#11339 feature/querystringquery-nestedqueries](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/pull/11339)

If you check the discussions, you'll see that this is not something that the ES folks think is worth diving into right now.

So the only way to query `nested` type objects is by using the `nested` queries/filters.

Comment: "This is currently not supported by Lucene." Aren't nested datatypes eventually flattened out to regular fields by Elasticsearch? What is there to support it in Lucene? It sounds more like an Elasticsearch issue

Comment: @DeanGurvitz Actually see this newer answer which should answer your question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61750497/4604579

Comment: @DeanGurvitz and to answer more specifically, no nested fields are not flattened out (that's the whole point of nested fields), it's not an ES issue, it was a Kibana one before ES 7.6