# In elasticsearch, is it possible to use regular queries for nested objects?

Tags: elasticsearch

In my elasticsearch index I have documents with a property that is a nested object like so:

```
{
  "my_index": {
    "mappings": {
      "my_type": {
        "properties": {
          "nested_prop": {
            "type": "nested",
            "properties": {
              "subprop1": {
                "type": "boolean"
              },
              "subprop2": {
                "type": "keyword"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I can search for objects with a nested query now, like so:

```
{
    "query": {
        "nested": {
            "path": "nested_prop",
            "query": {
                "bool": {
                    "must": [{
                        "term": {
                            "nested_prop.subprop1": "true"
                        }
                    }, {
                        "term": {
                            "nested_prop.subprop2": "SOME_KEY"
                        }
                    }]
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

So far so good. I'm building my elasticsearch queries with a pretty general mechanism from a querystring. So, I'd like to be able to still query the documents with a "regular" (non-nested) query like so:

```
{
    "query": {
        "term": {
            "nested_prop.subprop1": "true"
        }
    }
}
```

However, I only get empty results with that kind of query unless I wrap it into a `nested` query.

Is there a way to use a simple query with nested objects?

Comment: This answer might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35353952/is-it-possible-to-search-nested-objects-in-elasticsearch-with-the-lucene-query-s/35354869#35354869

Comment: Thanks, @Val, while I'm not intending to use the Lucene query syntax, I found an [answer](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/11322) linked from the answer you pointed me at: _"Nested fields need to be queries with nested queries/filters, because multiple documents can match and you need to be able to specify how these multiple scores should be reduced to a single score."_

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's not possible at the moment (ES 5.3.1) with `query_string`: https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/16551.

For other queries, no matter what you do with your nested fields, you need to have a `nested` query to make use of it.

Comment: So using `query_string` with nested objects (what the linked issue is about) is necessary for other queries like a plain `term` query (what I was asking)?

Comment: I'm confused. You mentioned `query_string`... No matter what you do with your nested fields, you need to have a `nested` query to make use of it.

Comment: I mentioned `query_string`? The link you posted is about `query_string` :) Thanks anyways. More info in my comment to the question.

Comment: I thought you did :-): `I'm building my elasticsearch queries with a pretty general mechanism from a querystring`. Indeed, it's not `query_string` and I may have misunderstood.

Comment: Sorry, that was vastly unprecise and misleading. I meant a string people send to my service from which I construct an elasticsearch query.