# ELK. Nested values are not found

Tags: elasticsearch, logging, kibana, elastic-stack, elk

I have index mapping like below:

```
 {
  "mapping": {
    "properties": {
      "MyMapProperty": {
        "type": "nested",
        "properties": {
          "first": {
            "type": "text",
            "fields": {
              "keyword": {
                "type": "keyword",
                "ignore_above": 256
              }
            }
          },
          "second": {
            "type": "text",
            "fields": {
              "keyword": {
                "type": "keyword",
                "ignore_above": 256
              }
            }
          },
        }
      },
      "SecondProperty": {
        "type": "text",
        "fields": {
          "keyword": {
            "type": "keyword",
            "ignore_above": 256
          }
        }
      },
      "ThirdProperty": {
        "type": "text",
        "fields": {
          "keyword": {
            "type": "keyword",
            "ignore_above": 256
          }
        }
      },
      "Timestamp": {
        "type": "date"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

After new document added, it source looks like below:

```
{
  "_index": "indexName",
  "_type": "_doc",
  "_id": "idlklkm43rgre",
  "_version": 1,
  "_score": 0,
  "_source": {
      "MyMapProperty": {
        "first": "value1",
        "second": "value2",
      },
      "SecondProperty": "value3",
      "ThirdProperty": "value4",
    },
    "fields": {
    "Timestamp": [
      "2020-05-11T12:54:49.049Z"
    ]
  }
}
```

So acltually I see in Kibana available fields:
**MyMapProperty.fist | MyMapProperty.second |SecondProperty | ThirdProperty**

Problem is that when I am trying to search MyMapProperty.fist : value - it finds nothing... However if I will search SecondProperty : value3 - it returns result.

I am trying to understand what I did wrong, is it kibana problem or elastic search, or maybe I am performing some strange actions. Could you please advise...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to remove type from index definition for "MyMapProperty".

```
"type": "nested"
```

After that nested attributes became searchable...

Comment: Beware, though, that if you ever need to store more than one value in `MyMapProperty` (i.e. an array), then you'll need to add nested back.

Comment: If you remove the 'nested' type, it's not a nested field/object anymore, which is the whole point of the question. This is very helpful: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/nested.html

Answer (score 1):

Before ES 7.6, it was not possible to search on nested fields inside Kibana. As of ES 7.6, it is now [possible to do so](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/kibana/current/release-highlights-7.6.0.html) using a specific search syntax, like this:

```
MyMapProperty:{ first:value }
```

You can try it out.

Note: this only works with KQL and not with Lucene because the Lucene expression language [doesn't support](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/11322) [nested fields](https://github.com/elastic/kibana/issues/1084)

Comment: I am using ES 7.3.2. Looking at your link I see there example on screenshot, however it is a bit different, I see there brackets "[ ]". 

So there is no option for me to search like this ?

Comment: This is [the link](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/kibana/7.6/kuery-query.html#_match_a_single_nested_document) you should be checking. Nope, unfortunately, you need to upgrade to 7.6 first if you want to be able to query nested fields in the Kibana search bar

Comment: Can I query it without kibana? using curl?

Comment: Yes, even in Kibana Dev Tools, you can query it like usual with a [`nested` DSL](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-nested-query.html) query, it's just that the search bar (i.e. the [`query_string` query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-query-string-query.html)) doesn't support searching on nested fields prior to ES 7.6

Comment: this answer shows KQL syntax and this works indeed. With Lucene queries, this doesn't work.

Comment: @fanfabbb yes because the Lucene syntax doesn't support nested fields, only KQL does

Comment: Thanks for the update. That linked issue is crazy. Very few mentions of "Lucene" though interestingly. Kibana supports this well I think.

Comment: @fanfabbb I've updated the links, the first one is the one.